# How to display items in custom adapter android

Tags: android, android-adapter

Hi I need to store items in custom adapter but I got issue while creating custom adapter. Please help me to resolve.

```
 private class Cast extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(Detailed_View.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);


    }

    private final String KeY = "";
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "TM";

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            return getCast();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> results_Cast) {
        updateListOfCast(results_Cast);
        dialog.cancel();


    };

    public ArrayList<String> getCast() throws IOException {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("https://themovie/3/movie/" + id
                + "/credit");
        stringBuilder.append("?key=" + key);
        URL url = new URL(stringBuilder.toString());
        // Log.d("urlstring",stringBuilder.toString() );

        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            // Establish a connection
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); // Required
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // get
                                                                    // TMDB
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // play
                                                                    // nicely.
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response code is: " + responseCode + " "
                    + conn.getResponseMessage());

            stream = conn.getInputStream();
            return parseCast(stringify(stream));
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<String> parseCast(String result) {
        String streamAsString = result;

        ArrayList<String> results_Cast = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(streamAsString);
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("cast");
            Log.d("array view", array.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject jsonMovieObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                results_Cast.add(jsonMovieObject.getString("name"));
                ids=jsonMovieObject.getString("id");
                results_Cast.add(jsonMovieObject.getString("character"));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("e", e.toString());
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Error parsing JSON. String was: "
                    + streamAsString);
        }
        // Log.d("resulted", results_Cast.toString());
        return results_Cast;
    }

    public String stringify(InputStream stream) throws IOException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Reader reader = null;
        reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        return bufferedReader.readLine();
    }
}

    // displays cast
    public void updateListOfCast(ArrayList<String> result) {

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cast_details);
            //Log.d("updateViewWithResults", result.toString());
            // Add results to listView.
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            Helper.getListViewSize(listView);
              gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(this, R.layout.test_row, result); // here I have issue.
            listView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long idss) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     String name = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                     Toast.makeText(Detailed_View.this, name+"Id"+ids, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                     .show();

                }
            });


         public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public GridAdapter(Activity a, int resource, ArrayList<String> result) { // here   it    displays error as The blank final field itemLists may not have been initialized
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) a
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         Resource = resource;
         results=result;
         activity=a;
        loader=new ImageLoader(a.getApplicationContext());

     }
 }
```

How to get items of name, id and character to display in custom adapter?

Comment: overide the getView method

Comment: i am getting error in constructor GridAdapter. check commented lines

Comment: moreover i have doubt is, how to get items stored in arraylist in another adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You have to overide all methods..

Example

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = items;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDesc;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
        context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);

    holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {     
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}
}
```